# str_extract generating NAs while using with mutate to remove substring at the beginning

Tags: r, stringr, dplyr

I am trying to remove a substring only at the start of a given string using the following code which works fine

```
str_extract('CNABC',"(?<=CN)([^,]+)"))
```

This removes the `CN` form the string `CNABC`
However, when I am using this code with dplyr, it is generating NAs. Any idea bout this?

```
a <- data %>%
mutate(B= str_extract(C,"(?<=CN)([^,]+)"))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this error: `data.frame(C = 'CNABC') %>% mutate(B = str_extract(C, "(?<=CN)([^,]+)"))` works as expected. Can you post `dput(head(data))`?

Comment: you are correct, some problem with the strings. cleaned it up. However, it is generating NA is the remaining rows which do not have this string. Thanks.

Comment: We still the to see the data, please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(data))`, with some rows giving wrong output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply replace the pattern, if found at the beginning of the string, with the empty string? If the pattern is not found, `sub` does nothing, unlike `stringr::str_extract`.

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(A = c('CNABC', 'XNABC', 'CXABC')) %>% 
  mutate(B = sub("^CN", "", A))
#      A     B
#1 CNABC   ABC
#2 XNABC XNABC
#3 CXABC CXABC
```